# Closing a client

Tags: python, asynchronous, network-programming, python-asyncio, aiohttp

There is the following code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

aut_token = ("token")

tasks = []
iter_flag = False

class WAPI:

    async def receiver(WAPI_S):
        async for msg in WAPI_S:
            data = msg.json()
            raise aiohttp.ClientError #test

    async def heartbeating(WAPI_S):
        while iter_flag:
            await WAPI_S.send_json({
                            "op": 1,
                            "d": None
                        })
            
            await asyncio.sleep(42.5)

    async def event_manager():
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        try:
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession().ws_connect("url") as WAPI_S: 
                task_receive = loop.create_task(WAPI.receiver(WAPI_S)); task_heartbeating = loop.create_task(WAPI.heartbeating(WAPI_S))
                tasks.append(task_receive); tasks.append(task_heartbeating)
                await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        except aiohttp.ClientError:
            global iter_flag
            iter_flag = False
            await asyncio.sleep(44)
            [task.cancel() for task in tasks]
            try:
                loop.close()
            except:
                loop.stop()
                
            
asyncio.run(WAPI.event_manager())
```

I want to correctly shutdown the client when the exception is raised. My implementation throws "RuntimeError: Event loop stopped before Future completed" exception while executing. How to do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In method `event_manager`, the statement:

```py
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession().ws_connect("url") as WAPI_S:
```

needs to be replaced with:

```py
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                async with session.ws_connect("url") as WAPI_S:
```

Also, it is considered anti-Pythonic to use a list comprehension for its side effects. See [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects) So you really *should* replace:

```py
            [task.cancel() for task in tasks]
```

with:

```py
            for task in tasks:
                task.cancel()
```

Putting this all together:

```py
    async def event_manager():
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        try:
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                async with session.ws_connect("url") as WAPI_S: 
                    task_receive = loop.create_task(WAPI.receiver(WAPI_S)); task_heartbeating = loop.create_task(WAPI.heartbeating(WAPI_S))
                    tasks.append(task_receive); tasks.append(task_heartbeating)
                    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        except aiohttp.ClientError:
            global iter_flag
            iter_flag = False
            await asyncio.sleep(44)
            for task in tasks:
                task.cancel()
            try:
                loop.close()
            except:
                loop.stop()
```

Comment: Everything works. Thank you.

However my question is, what is the technical difference between yours and mine's event_manager implementation? Could you explain?

Comment: Each method, i.e. `aiohttp.ClientSession()` and `session.ws_connect()`, requires the `async` keyword, and so must be separate `async` statements.